# array to string convert and str_replace usage

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace, implode

I am tring to convert an array to string, than wanna change some chracters with str_replace. Everything works fine except convertion. What is the proplem in my code?

```
function tr_cevir($text = "") {
    //converts turkish charters in to english chracters
    $TR = array('ç', 'Ç', 'ı', 'İ', 'ş', 'Ş', 'ğ', 'Ğ', 'ö', 'Ö', 'ü', 'Ü', 'I');
    $EN = array('c', 'c', 'i', 'i', 's', 's', 'g', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'i');
    $text = str_replace($TR, $EN, $text);
    $text = str_replace(" ", "", $text);
    return $text;
}

$my_array = array(çali, Şeli, Ğahmet);

$string = implode(", ", $my_array);

$string_converted = tr_cevir($string);

echo $string_converted; //output returns null
```

How can i get the output like:

> cali,seli,gahmet

Comment: `$my_array = array(çali, Şeli, Ğahmet);` -> `$my_array = array('çali', 'Şeli', 'Ğahmet');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your whole code with this:

```
$my_array = array('çali', 'Şeli', 'Ğahmet');

$string = implode(", ", $my_array);

$string_converted = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $string);

echo $string_converted;
```

[`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_array = array('çali', 'Şeli', 'Ğahmet');
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = array(çali, Şeli, Ğahmet);
```

You forgot the ' or " around the strings.

Comment: And why don't you put the " " and "" pair in the corresponding arrays? You would only need 1 str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to quote your array contents:

```
$my_array = array('çali', 'Seli', 'Gahmet');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:

```
$converted = iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

It will transliterate any non ascii characters to their ascii 'nearest equivalent'.
more info about [`iconv()`](http://php.net/iconv)

Answer (score 0):

To start with, quote the values in the array:

```
$my_array = array("çali", "Şeli", "Ğahmet");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be required to add your own code for translation, there is already library present for same.Please check 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php